# Chinese mutant who can absorb a tiny fraction of every Chinese person's lifeforce?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, super-hero, mutant

It was Marvel, 99% sure of that. And I'm also 99% certain that, given this, the character in question was a mutant. It was a one-off appearance, although the character might have been reused later, in a retooled form of not. I'm not following current comics, so I can't say if he's currently in Krakoa or not. Is he?

Basically, he can summon like 0.01% of the vital energy of every person who is sufficiently similar, genetically, to himself, for a few minutes. Meaning, all the Chinese. Meaning, he becomes 100,000x as strong as a human for that time. (Numbers might not be exactly those, but you get the idea.)

Who was this guy?

Comment: [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man), presumably? First result when Googling your title, FWIW. Don't really have time to write an answer up though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I feel like they made the character a *tad* stereotypical there, seeing as his powers literally come from both Communism and China's population growth. But then, this *is* the company that gave us *Captain America*, a man who dresses in the colors of the American flag.

Comment: And given one of Collective Man's teammates literally has the power to rapidly give birth to new Chinese heroes...

Comment: Yes...more than a little problematic. The American heroes get all manner of cool talents, whereas the Chinese heroes get powers that are based on broad aspects of China's political system or outright stereotypes. Of course, Marvel has had even worse character ideas (*cough* the bulimic superhero whose power is based on overeating and self-purging *cough* the superhero who is a racist White man who turns into a caricature of a Black man *cough*).

Comment: I don't know if this is racist but it reminds me of things like, what happens if everyone in China jumps off a chair at the same time? Or, for American merchants, what if we could sell just one pair of shoes to everyone in China? These were things people said before China became a major economic power.

Comment: Ah, and I misremember. Mother of Champions is a *DC* character with the power of fecundity.

Comment: @Adamant: You should see someone about that cough... especially in these times... :P

Comment: Not sure that his abilities are limited to *just* being able to absorb Chinese people, or if he merely chose them because they were close by and convenient.  Theoretically he could merge with every human on Earth if he wanted to?  Realistically, there's probably enough genetic diversity just within China that the entire population isn't really much more closely related to eachother than they are to their neighbors, or even the rest of humanity.  But why let realism get in the way of a perfectly good metaphor?

Comment: What the.... ?!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Fun fact, China houses one of the few surviving 22 chromosome humans.

Answer (score 10):

As noted by TheLethalCarrot, [Collective Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Man) matches what you're looking for.

> The **Collective Man** (**Sun**, **Chang**, **Ho**, **Lin**, and **Han Tao-Yu**) is a Chinese superhero appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics. The Collective Man is actually an identity shared by the Tao-Yu brothers, a set of quintuplets. They possess the mutant power to merge into one body, which variously possesses the collective abilities of all five men or all the people of China. The brothers also share a psychic/spiritual link that allows them to telepathically communicate and teleport to one another.

Comment: Is that character based on the story of the [5 Chinese brothers](https://archive.org/details/five-chinese-brothers)?

Comment: @PeterTurner I've found no indication that it's the case. He seems a more generic gestalt character.